# Convert nested JSON into relational table with PostgreSQL functions and Materialistic views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, database, postgresql, view

I have been struggling with Materialistic views with Postgresql. My application is in Ruby on Rails with PostgreSQL. One of the tables called "Submissions" has a column "answers_json" with type jsonb which stores nested JSON. The example format is added below:

```
{"comment"=>{"252"=>{"123"=>""}, "318"=>{"313"=>"", "556"=>"", "622"=>""}},
   "category"=>{"252"=>{"123"=>"Label4 Score String"}, "318"=>{"313"=>"Score String 1", "556"=>"String Score", "622"=>"None"}},
   "question"=>
    {"252"=>{"123"=>"Question 1"},
     "318"=>{"313"=>"Add issues and pull requests to your board ", "556"=>"Alignment Question 1", "622"=>"hello there"}},
   "question_weights"=>{"252"=>{"123"=>"1"}, "318"=>{"313"=>"1", "556"=>"1", "622"=>"1"}},
   "question_category"=>{"252"=>{"123"=>"Culture"}, "318"=>{"313"=>"Alignment", "556"=>"Alignment", "622"=>"Alignment"}},
   "question_weights_calc"=>{"252"=>{"123"=>0.0}, "318"=>{"313"=>0.0, "556"=>0.0, "622"=>0.0}}}
```

For all keys i.e. "comment", "category", "question" etc. in above hash, the JSON structure is consistent. Here, The keys "252" and "318" corresponds to "category_id"(Model Category). The keys inside "123","313", "556", "622" are question_ids(Model Question). The JSON shows questions associated with each category and required values associated with each question i.e. weights, category name, etc.

The goal is to convert this nested JSON into a relational table with the help of Materialistic views and functions provided by PostgreSQL. The tricky part is that the keys will vary for numerous records. For another submission record, the category and questions ids could be different. I want to convert this into a simple relational table with the lowest-level details. For example, for the above structure the column header and respective values would be:

```
|ques_id|category_id|ques_weight|ques_weight_calc|ques_category|question  |comment
| ------| ----------|-----------| ---------------|-------------|----------|-------
| 123   | 252       |1          |0.0             |Culture      |Question 1|""
```

I am quite confused about this. Can anyone guide me? Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK example value mention in your question can not be stored in a `jsonb` column.

Comment: Create an array of hash from the JSON where hash will have all the attributes of the DB table and then call `YourModel.instert_all`(rails 6)